# A use case for MySql JSON datatype

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I am creating a DB-schema for a website on which users can write the `Articles`. I was almost done with the design and suddenly I read few blogs on `JSON datatype` in `MySQL`.
As per blogs, there are certain use cases where `JSON` can be used:

1. for storing metadata. e.g a product having its height, widths,
   colour stored as JSON.
2. for storing the non-standard schema type data
3. for storing the tags as JSON. e.g this question could have tags -
   mysql, JSON. So the blogs recommended using a JSON structure that
   holds all the `tags`.

The last one is doubtful to me. Why?
Ok I have stored the tag value in JSON as `{"tags": ["mysql", "JSON", "mysql-datatype"]}`. I agree this helps in easily maintaining the tags with the Article.
But suppose a user wants to read all the article related to `mysql` tags!! If I have been maintained a separate table for `article_id` - `tags_id`, I could have easily get all the `Articles` based on the `tags`. But with `JSON` this could be a very hectic requirement, though this can be solved but with a cost. Slower queries ofcourse.
This is my schema for Article:
[image]
Is my way of thinking correct or am I missing something here? Love to hear some suggestions.

Comment: I would highly recommend against using JSON data for anything you might want to search on. The functions available in MySQL are not powerful enough. Keep separate tables instead.

Comment: I think your thinking is refreshingly 'on the money'

Comment: @Strawberry  'on the money' - I didn't get that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The task you're trying to do, to associate articles with tags, is better handled as a many-to-many relationship. For this you need another table, which I believe is the `article_tags` table in your diagram.

This makes it easy to query for all articles with a given tag.

```
SELECT ...
FROM article AS a
JOIN article_tags AS t USING (article_id)
WHERE t.topic_id = 1234 -- whatever is the id for the topic you want to read
```

Doing the same thing if you use JSON to store tags in the article table is different:

```
SELECT ...
FROM article AS a
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(a.article_tags, '1234')
```

This might seem simpler, since it does not require a JOIN.

But any search that puts the column you need to search inside a function call will not be able to use an index. This will result in a table-scan, so the query will always search every row in the table. As your table grows, it will become slower and slower to do this search "the hard way."

The first method with the `article_tags` table uses an index two ways:

1. Look up the entries in `article_tags` matching the desired tag quickly
2. Look up the corresponding articles by their primary key quickly

No table-scan needed. The query reads only the rows that are going to be in the query result.

My take on the JSON data type and JSON functions follows this general rule:

**Reference JSON columns in the select-list, but not in the WHERE clause.**

That is, if you can do your search conditions in the WHERE clause using non-JSON columns, you can take advantage of indexes to make the query as efficient as possible.

Once the relevant rows have been found that way, then you may extract parts of your JSON data to return in the result. Compared to the cost of searching JSON documents in a table-scan, the cost of extracting a field from the JSON documents on the rows matching your search is relatively small.

The select-list is not evaluated for rows unless they match the search conditions.

Comment: Is there any performance benefit of using JSON instead of having multiple column for that data? I think that saves some amount of DB space, please correct me on this.

Comment: No, JSON takes **twice the space** for the equivalent data on average in my test. See my presentation [How to Use JSON in MySQL Wrong](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-use-json-in-mysql-wrong), slides 52-59 are about storage.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it myself yet, but from my understanding I wouldn't use JSON for items you'd want to lookup / filter by. For example: I'd use it for storing a JSON config where the config schema might change frequently (meaning no DB schema changes).

However it looks like MySQL does have functions to search in the JSON, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html

`JSON_CONTAINS(target, candidate[, path])`

Not sure on the efficiency of this compared to an indexed string column.